In Anchor, how can I check if an account is initialized or not before accessing its fields to avoid AccountNotInitialized errors?
In my Anchor program, I want to check if an account (delegate_storage) is initialized for a given signer in the send_notification function. If delegate_storage exists, I’ll check parameters like is_delegate; if it doesn’t, I need to verify if signer matches channel and proceed accordingly. However, I’m encountering an AccountNotInitialized error when delegate_storage is uninitialized. How can I handle both cases (initialized and uninitialized) flexibly without triggering errors?
pub fn send_notification(ctx: Context<SendNotificationCTX>,
    channel: Pubkey,
    recipient: Pubkey,
    message: Vec<u8>,
) -> Result<()> {
        let caller = &ctx.accounts.signer;
        let delegate_storage = &ctx.accounts.delegate_storage;

        let is_valid = (caller == channel) || (delegate_storage.delegate == caller.key() && delegate_storage.is_delegate)

        if is_valid {
            emit!(SendNotification {
                channel: channel,
                recipient,
                message,
            });
        }

    Ok(())
}

#[account]
pub struct DelegatedNotificationSenders {
    pub channel: Pubkey,
    pub delegate: Pubkey,
    pub is_delegate: bool,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(channel: Pubkey)]
pub struct SendNotificationCTX<'info> {
    #[account(
        seeds = [
            DELEGATE,
            channel.key().as_ref(),
            signer.key().as_ref()
        ],
        bump
    )]
    pub delegate_storage: Account<'info, DelegatedNotificationSenders>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}


Anchor version: 0.29.0,
Solana cli version: 1.18.25

You have a few options,

mark the delegate_storage account as an untyped UncheckedAccount. This was ou won't get the Account not initialized error,

You can then check if the account is initialized by checking if the account has data/doesn't have data in it
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,

    /// CHECK: checked in ix body
    #[account(mut)]
    pub delegate_storage: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
}

    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        let delegate_storage = ctx.accounts.delegate_storage.to_account_info();
        
        // the account is initialized
        if !delegate_storage.data_is_empty() {
            // validate account is correct

            // 1. check program owner
            // 2. check whether derived address matches one provided
            
        }

        // the account isn't initialized

        Ok(())
    }

The drawback of this is you'll need to handle account validation to make sure that the account supplied is indeed what you were expecting.

Use init_if_needed macro. This must be enabled in anchor using the init-if-needed feature.

This macro will initialize your account if it isn't initialized already, but be careful as you can suffer from reinitialization attacks
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(init_if_needed, payer = authority, space = 8 + 100, seeds = [], bump)]
    pub delegate_storage: Account<'info, DelegatedNotificationSenders>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

  pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        let delegate_storage = ctx.accounts.delegate_storage.clone();

        Ok(())
    }

re-initialization attacks -> https://solana.com/developers/courses/program-security/reinitialization-attacks
